# Linux logs are polluted by kernel “vfs-change discarded” messages

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel

today I noticed those lines appearing in my dmesg command output:

```
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[75]: 1527614896 file-deleted, /etc/.#grouptKnxCp, (null)
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[77]: 1527614896 file-deleted, /etc/.#gshadow12IUYc, (null)
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[221]: 1527614896 file-created, /var/log/journal/83d7b3d9fdbb4d9a871a34a0eedda56c/system@00056d5b8f416810-f3a90a1e0bad9ec5.journal~, (null)
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[121]: 1527614896 file-created, /var/log/journal/83d7b3d9fdbb4d9a871a34a0eedda56c/system.journal, (null)
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[159]: 1527614896 file-deleted, /var/log/journal/83d7b3d9fdbb4d9a871a34a0eedda56c/user-1000@0005548753fe89aa-c56d2f821cdb87e6.journal~, (null)
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[102]: 1527614896 file-created, /etc/udev/hwdb.bin, (null)
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[132]: 1527614903 file-created, /var/lib/systemd/catalog/database, (null)
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[71]: 1527614903 dir-created, /tmp/.X11-unix, (null)
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[71]: 1527614903 dir-created, /tmp/.ICE-unix, (null)
May 29 20:00:32 PC kernel: vfs-change discarded[71]: 1527614903 dir-created, /tmp/.XIM-unix, (null)
```

I wanted to understand what those messages mean. They appear sometimes when system deletes or creates a file/directory. It does not seem to be dependent on any specific drive or partition or filesystem as / (root partition), my RAID partition and even /tmp are affected.

As I investigated further I found out they were appearing since about 10 days. There are at least thousnds of those and it makes hard to read dmesg or journalctl output because of that.

I tried to google some parts of the lines but couldn't find any clue except that it is probably Virtual File System log (from kernel).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is printed by the kernel module of [deepin-anything](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-anything), the file indexer of Linux Deepin. (Apparently, they started doing the indexing via the kernel itself, because fanotify wasn't suitable?)

The warning was [removed a few days ago](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-anything/commit/7a6d87c491982445cd0dbb05b97e88a7cd96de9c).

Comment: When Google fails, try Debian Code Search. When _that_ fails, search GitHub.

Comment: Thanks so much for help, I was about to ask for the way of solving but you were faster than a thought. I'm pretty sure your searching way works but I'm currently unable to find this. Probably writing wrong thing or sth. But that is sth I will learn. Andd although I manually updated the package it still gives the errors, but the problem probably lies in me not upgrading correctly, so I will figure it out. Now that I know where it originates from I'm able to do much more. Thanks so much again, and have a great day.